# How do I GROUP BY the first expression of a UNION ALL query in Knex.JS?

Tags: sql, mysql, knex.js

I have a table `entries` linked with another table `categories`.
There is also a column `is_marked` of type `BOOLEAN`.

The user may want to see the marked entries separately, so I wish to show the count of

- Every category
- Every marked entry

My plan was to use UNION ALL to achieve this. This is the query to fetch the category count, as well as to fetch the marked entries:

```sql
(
SELECT 
    cat.category_name AS `name`, 
    cat.category_id AS `id`, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT e.entry_id) AS `entry_count` 
FROM `categories` AS `cat` 
    INNER JOIN `entries` AS `e` USING (category_id)
GROUP BY cat.category_name
) UNION ALL (
SELECT
    "Marked Entry" AS `name`, 
    -1 AS `id`, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT e2.entry_id) AS `entry_count` 
 FROM `entries` AS `e2` 
    WHERE `e2`.`is_marked` = 1
)
```

Following this plan, I made this knexJS code:

```js
const query = knex
    .select('cat.category_name AS name', 'cat.category_id AS id')
    .countDistinct('e.entry_id AS entry_count')
    .from('categories AS cat')
    .innerJoin('entries AS e', 'e.category_id', 'cat.category_id')
    .groupBy('cat.category_name');

const markedQuery = knex
    .select(knex.raw('"Marked Entry" AS `name`'), knex.raw('-1 AS `id`'))
    .countDistinct('e2.entry_id AS entry_count')
    .from('entries AS e2')
    .where('e2.is_marked', '=', 1);

query.unionAll([markedQuery]);
```

However, this code puts the `GROUP BY` statement after the `UNION ALL`, which results in a 1140 SQL error.

```sql
select 
    `cat`.`category_name` as `name`, 
    `cat`.`category_id` as `id`, 
    count(distinct `e`.`entry_id`) as `entry_count` 
from `categories` as `cat` 
    inner join `entries` as `e`
    on `e`.`category_id` = `cat`.`category_id`
union all
select
    "Marked Entry" AS `name`, 
    -1 AS `id`, 
    count(distinct `e2`.`entry_id`) as `entry_count` 
from `entries` as `e2`
    where `e2`.`is_marked` = ?
group by `cat`.`category_name`
```

How can I force the `GROUP BY` to apply to the first expression?
Inverting the query order does fix this particular issue, but I can't guarantee that future situations can be fixed the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by supplying both of your queries to the `knex.unionAll()` function rather than calling `unionAll` on your first query. Also the second argument allows you to specify that you want to add parentheses around each query like so

```js
knex.unionAll([query, markedQuery], true);
```